# How to POST to google form by Flutter. The response is always 400 (POSTMAN'S result is 200 OK)

Tags: flutter, dart, post, postman, x-www-form-urlencoded

I tried to POST to google form with flutter, but the response is always 400.
When I use POSTMAN, it succeeds.
I cannot understand why it fails with flutter.

I tried http package and dio package, but the result is always 400.
What is the problem? If there is a suggestion for solving this, please tell me.

The code I tried is as follows.

1. http package (http: ^0.12.2)

```
void _request() async {
    String url =
        'https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSc5aAwiiLJ2qJhF-ngGFfRl8m8yEJs8gTipY7pnNQkxGcJ_1w/formResponse';

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    };
    String body = json.encode(
      {
        'entry.844954850': 'bug',
        'entry.479013015': 'dsfa',
      },
    );
    http.Response resp = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);
    if (resp.statusCode != 200) {
      print('Failed to post ${resp.statusCode}');
    } else {
      print(resp.body);
    }
  }
```

The result is

```
I/flutter ( 5834): Failed to post 400
```

2. Dio package (dio: ^3.0.10)

```
Future _request_dio() async {
    final dio = Dio();
    final url =
        'https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSc5aAwiiLJ2qJhF-ngGFfRl8m8yEJs8gTipY7pnNQkxGcJ_1w/formResponse';

    String body = json.encode(
      {
        'entry.844954850': 'bug',
        'entry.479013015': 'dsfa',
      },
    );

    var data = await dio
        .post(
      url,
      data: body,
      options: Options(contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType),
    )
        .then((response) {
      print(response.data);
      return response.data;
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
      return null;
    });
  }
```

The result is

```
I/flutter ( 5834): DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400]
```

When I use POSTMAN and succeeded, following HTTP codes are used in POSTMAN.

```
POST /forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSc5aAwiiLJ2qJhF-ngGFfRl8m8yEJs8gTipY7pnNQkxGcJ_1w/formResponse HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: S=spreadsheet_forms=yClaqeCIC2953sdlxK8fzZb97ycQG4UFviYCNtUBFtg; NID=204=vu3hzpnGl1iqwJCJgR_bPkjmqdx4uvEQYIfxgZWm9sc6KJjoOSZDFpMrSn0AtlmqjJeFb0JkX6MJnpIHtYXgXebI7CbKJy4JI_1hOfFe8fiMjM6qEbKw4BhNjaDzHyKTk6uoU4mpG34i01A2rEbch7xCs6Z_cvwfPhNvFWH_xGI

entry.844954850=bug&entry.479013015=fsda
```

The flutter doctor's result is

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082], locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 1.20.4 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (5 days ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reproduce your case in Postman with form-data:
[image: postman]

and for control, i'm using curl for testing :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSc5aAwiiLJ2qJhF-ngGFfRl8m8yEJs8gTipY7pnNQkxGcJ_1w/formResponse' \
    --form 'entry.844954850=bug' \
    --form 'entry.479013015=dsfa'
```

now i can reproduce this Post request in flutter:

```
void _request() async {
  String url =
      'https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSc5aAwiiLJ2qJhF-ngGFfRl8m8yEJs8gTipY7pnNQkxGcJ_1w/formResponse';

  Map<String, String> headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  };
  // String body = json.encode(...)      //------------> Before
  Map<String, String> requestBody = <String, String>{ // After
    'entry.844954850': 'bug',
    'entry.479013015': 'dsfa'
  };

  http.Response resp =
      await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: requestBody);
  print(resp);
  if (resp.statusCode != 200) {
    print('Failed to post ${resp.statusCode}');
  } else {
    print(resp.body);
  }
}
```

status code in debug mode:

[image: result]

For dio, it's same replace json and your request is formatted correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick answer. This worked well!

Comment: The problem using maps is that you can not have two identical keys. And when you have questions with multiple selectable options, it requires you to send multiple entries with the same id. I tried this but it doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/a/63656894/7927429 Any idea?

Comment: This is not working for me, I can POST data from Postman as ```multipart/form-data```but when I try to do it using ```application/x-www-form-urlencoded```the response is 400 - Bad request. Someone has the same issue?