# http post request giving type-errors

Tags: flutter, http

In this instance, i have details of an item entered by user and need to add them to backend server. Here is my method:

```
Future<AddItemResponseModel> AddItem(
  String name,
  String description,
  String picture, // image encoded to base64 String
  List<String> tags,
  bool liked,
  String token,
) async {
  final String url = "API_URL";
  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
    "name": name,
    "description": description,
    "picture": picture,
    "date": "date",
    "tags": tags,
    "like": liked,
    "location": "something"
  }, headers: {
    "authtype": "custom",
    "x-access-token": token
  });
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final String responseString = response.body;
    print(responseString);
    return AddItemResponseModelFromJson(responseString);
  } else {
    // Error message to user
  }
}
```

And here is the onTap function of a GestureDetector widget that calls this method.

```
onTap: () async {
                                    if (checkCondition) {
                                      final AddItemResponseModel item =
                                          await AddItem(
                                        itemName, // name
                                        itemDescription, // description 
                                        _image64, // image encoded to base64 String
                                        tagNames, // List<String>
                                        true,  // liked
                                        token, // x-access-token
                                      );
                                      setState(() {
                                        _item = item;  // _item is of datatype <AddItemResponseModel> created to be accessed across this page
                                      });
                                      if (_item.success == true) {
                                        Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  ItemAdded()),
                                        );
                                      }
                                    }
                                    setState(() {
                                      if (screen_no < 3) screen_no += 1;
                                    });
                                  }
```

I get the following error, but haven't been able to diagnose the cause.

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
#0      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:_internal/cast.dart:288:25)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
#2      CastMap.forEach (dart:_internal/cast.dart:287:13)
#3      mapToQuery (package:http/src/utils.dart:17:7)
#4      Request.bodyFields= (package:http/src/request.dart:137:12)
#5      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:87:17)
#6      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
#7      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:69:16)
#8      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:20)
#9      post (package:http/http.dart:68:5)
#10     AddItem (package:krunch_app/Pages/AddItem/itemAddPage.dart:37:31)
#11     _ItemAddPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:krunch_app/Pages/AddItem/itemAddPage.dart:492:49)
#12     _ItemAddPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:krunc<…>
```

Thanks for all the help in advance.

EDIT-1:

This is my AddItemResponseModel

```
class AddItemResponseModel {
  AddItemResponseModel({this.success, this.error, this.id});

  bool? success;
  String? error;
  String? id;

  factory AddItemResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      AddItemResponseModel(
          success: json["success"], error: json["error"], id: json["id"]);
}
```

AddItem is just a function which returns a AddItemResponseModel datatype by decoding the json response

Comment: can you add json response which you are getting from api?

Comment: not getting a response, something goes wrong before that

Comment: what i am saying is if you call this api from postman or any other software like that what response you are getting?, because this error shows that your models data type is not matching with some field, basically you are receiving `String` but in that same place tour model needs `List<String>`.

Comment: I tried that, it says request cannot be sent

Comment: try ```Map responseString = json.decode(response.body);```

Comment: Post your json response.

Comment: @test already doing that: `return AddItemResponseModelFromJson(responseString);` does that only

Answer (score 0):

Your error is right in the Unhandled Exception. You are trying to cast your **tags** field as a ***List*<*String*>** type, when your API response gives you only a String. As is for now, try to change the type value like this:

```
String tags
```

Comment: No, API response only gives a bool value success. tags is a list<String>, so cant convert it to string

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using `package:http`, from the documentation for [`http.post`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client/post.html):

> `body` sets the body of the request. It can be a `String`, a `List<int>` or a `Map<String, String>`.

You are passing a `Map` for `body`, so that `Map` is expected to have `String` keys and `String` values.  You are attempting to include `tags` as a value to that `Map`, yet `tags` is a `List<String>`. (Similarly, `liked` will also produce an error since it is a `bool` and not a `String`.)

If you need to pass multiple items for a field, you must combine them and encode them to a single `String` first.

Also see: [Dart Http POST with duplicate key form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68534296/)

Comment: After converting both tags and liked to String, i get this `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)`

Comment: @Calladrus2k1 That sounds like a separate problem.  I can't help you with that if you don't provide any details about where it's coming from. (I presume you're getting that exception when attempting to decode the response.  What is the response?  Possibly the response isn't what you expect because the server rejected your request.)

Comment: I am getting no response, from postman it says "could not send request"

Comment: @Calladrus2k1 As I said, it sounds like a separate problem.  It's quite possible (if not likely) that the server is rejecting your request because however you're encoding your `List<String>` as a single `String` isn't what the server expects.  Or maybe there's something else malformed in your request body.  If so, it's going to be specific to your API/server.

Comment: @Calladrus2k1 Another possibility is that you're doing nothing wrong when sending the request and that whatever request you're making is *supposed* to receive an empty string in response, but your `AddItemResponseModelFromJson` function does not handle that.